# Set jInternalFrame background to transparent

Tags: java, background, transparency, jinternalframe

I am having trouble setting the background of my jInternalFrame to transparent. I have tried setting jInternalFrameVarName.Opacity(false), but it doesn't do the trick. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems with jInternalFrame and transparent background before when I used Nimbus Look and feel. I don't know is it you case, but you can try way what I solved this problem.

I solved this like described on this [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1358501?tstart=21300) (aterai's answer). Analyze his solution, i think that it is good start point and you will solve your problem based on this idea.